# Pushing time to browser using channel

Tags: go

I'm trying to push the time to the browser using channels, so I wrote the below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type DataPasser struct {
    logs chan string
}

func main() {
    passer := &DataPasser{logs: make(chan string)}
    go func() {
        for {
            passer.logs <- time.Now().String()
        }
    }()

    http.HandleFunc("/", passer.handleHello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)

}

func (p *DataPasser) handleHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    for {
        w.Write([]byte(<-p.logs))
    }
    /*  for {
            io.WriteString(w, <-p.logs)
        }
    */
}
```

It worked by kept adding new lines with each new time, as below:
[image]

What I need is to get single line, that is cleared and replaced with the new time everytime the server sending time to it? any help?

**UPDATE**

I tried using `SSE` server sent event, as below but did not work:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type DataPasser struct {
    logs chan string
}

func main() {
    passer := &DataPasser{logs: make(chan string)}
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer t.Stop()

    go func() {
        for range t.C {
            passer.logs <- time.Now().String()
        }
    }()

    http.HandleFunc("/", passer.handleHello)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)

}

func (p *DataPasser) handleHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    setupCORS(&w, r)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "Internal error", 500)
        return
    }
    for {
        w.Write([]byte(<-p.logs))
        //  c := []byte(<-p.logs)
        //  fmt.Fprint(w, c)
        flusher.Flush()
    }
    /*  for {
            io.WriteString(w, <-p.logs)
        }
    */
    //  w.Write([]byte("Hi, from Service: " + ws.name))

}

func setupCORS(w *http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
}
```

And the html file as:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="counter"  width="500" height="600">
</body>
    <script>
        var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:9999/");
        source.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log(event)
            var counter = event.data; // JSON.parse(event.data);
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: @BellinghamBoss I tried but failed, kindly see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application must write the response in the text/event-stream format:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n\n", <-p.logs)
```

There are other problems.  The handler should exit when the client disconnects or when there's an error writing to the response. The handler should flush the headers before waiting for the first event.  Here's the updated code:

```
func (p *DataPasser) handleHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    setupCORS(w, r)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "Internal error", 500)
        return
    }
    flusher.Flush()
    done := r.Context().Done()
    defer fmt.Println("EXIT")
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            // the client disconnected
            return
        case m := <-p.logs:
            if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n\n", m); err != nil {
                // Write to connection failed. Subsequent writes will probably fail.
                return
            }
            flusher.Flush()
        }
    }
}
```